# How to open new window with gecko browser?

Tags: c#, gecko

How to open new window with gecko browser? I used CreateNewWindow but it not work.

```
GeckoWebBrowser gecko= new GeckoWebBrowser();
gecko.CreateNewWindow(1);
gecko.Navigate(url);
```

Please help me!

Thanks you!

Comment: Create a new form and add the gecko component to it. If you got an existing form with the gecko component, simply create a new instance of that.